# Prevent multiple api calls inside useEffect reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am working with react hooks and stuck at one place.

This is the function which is setting the state from the params.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isInteger(searchParams.get("pageNo"))) {
      setState({ ...state, activePage: parseInt(searchParams.get("pageNo")) });
      setCount(count + 1);  //setting here again
      firstRef.current = true;
    } else {
      setState({ ...state, activePage: 1 });
    }
  }, []);
```

This is my useEffect function to call api here the api name is `videoGridState`. Here the api is calling single time with no issue.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (firstRef.current) {
      videoGridState();
      firstRef.current = false;
    } else {
      const timer = setTimeout(() => {
        videoGridState(false);
      }, 1000);
      return () => clearTimeout(timer);
    }
  }, [count]);
```

It is calling the api two times. One on the first load and second when it is setting the state from params. How can I prevent it from calling from multiple times within a sort method?

Comment: It might be called again because `count` changes value before `firstRef.current` results in true. What happens when you empty the array at the end?

Comment: Then how will I call the api `videoGridState` on change of `count` because count is also using when I using `searchText`

Comment: @Profer Are both of the `useEffect`s within the same component?

Comment: *"...within a sort method"* There's no `sort` in the code shown (nor `searchText`, which you refer to above). It's hard to understand from the code in the question how `count` is used, and why you add to count once on mount if `isInteger(searchParams.get("pageNo"))` is truthy. Please update your question with a runnable [mcve] demonstrating the problem using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the api two times, the issue maybe the prop count has change or is one of three things

### This component appears twice in your page

This one should be obvious.

### Something higher up the tree is unmounting and remounting

The component is being forced to unmount and remount on its initial render. This could be something like a "key" change happening higher up the tree. you need to go up each level with this useEffect until it renders only once. then you should be able to find the cause or the remount.

### React.Strict mode is on

> StrictMode renders components twice (on dev but not production) in
> order to detect any problems with your code and warn you about them
> (which can be quite useful).